# How can I choose PDF file from my phone library for attachment in iOS app?

Tags: ios, attachment

I am using image picker to upload image from camera roll. Can I do same for PDF or any other doc format? If no, then what would be the alternative method to use PDF as an attachment?

Comment: Where do you want to get the PDF file from?

Comment: From iPhone directory.If any PDF or doc is available

Comment: What iPhone directory? Please be specific.

Comment: If I download a PDF file from a website then where would it save ?on which directory it would save from that I wanna upload it like image picker

Comment: Suppose I am having two PDF s having name a.PDF & b.PDF in my IPhone and want to be attachment in my application so how could I get. It? That is it

Comment: What app are you using to save a PDF from a website?

Comment: U didn't get  my question.any application when u upload a image from camera roll or gallery same I want to do with PDF or any attachment file .thanks hope u might get it

Comment: Basically, OP wants to browse for a file inside the phone and upload that file to his server. I'm actually looking for the same answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also tried to do the same but failed.
At last I integrated Dropbox with my app and then uploaded the PDF and Doc files. Dropbox integration would be an easy and handy option.

Here is the link for Dropbox
https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/sdks/ios

Google drive is also an alternate that you can use to upload the documents but it is hard to integrate.

Here is the link for Google Drive
https://developers.google.com/drive/ios/quickstart

Hope it saves your time! 
All the best